# ActiveRecord: Do I need both belongs_to and has_one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have 2 models, namely **user** and **userprofile**. There is a **one-to-one relationship** between user and userprofile.

```
class Userprofile < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :fname, :lname, :iswoman, :age, :urlphoto, :user_id

   belongs_to: user

end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :name, :provider, :uid

   has_one: userprofile
end
```

I'd like to know whether I need both class to set the connection or having just either **belongs_to** or **has_one** is enough? The same is true for the other methods, such as **has-many**.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You define the association wherever you will need it. If at some point you need to say `user.userprofile`, then include `has_one :userprofile` in `User`. Likewise, if you need to say `userprofile.user`, then include `belongs_to user` in `Userprofile`.

In other words, associations are relative. You can specify that model A `has_one :b` without specifying that model B `belongs_to :a`. You simply define what you need. The same goes for one-to-many and many-to-many associations.

Just be sure to have migrated `user_id` to the "userprofiles" table.

Comment: make sense. Also, do I need to add :dependent => destroy? to make sure that when a user is deleted, his profile gets deleted as well? Finally, to take effect, do I need to run rake db:migrate?

Comment: Yes. By placing `:dependent => destroy` in `Userprofile`, you are telling the model to destroy any userprofile record whose user no longer exists. And yes, you need to run `rake db:migrate` once you have created a migration that adds `user_id` to the `Userprofile` table. This foreign key is used to enforce the association.

Answer (score 1):

Having just a belongs_to relationship between userprofiles and user does default to has_one. However, it would be wise (Rails-proper) to specify the association on both models.

After all, if you wanted a has_many association (etc) you would want to specify that.

Check out http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html for more info