# belongs_to belongs_to association only no has_many or has_one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, model-associations, belongs-to

Can you have a `belongs_to` `belongs_to` relationship in Rails?

[Search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18933994/can-belongs-to-work-without-has-many-or-has-one) [results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13436889/activerecord-do-i-need-both-belongs-to-and-has-one) gave me two results.  The fact that I can't find very much info on the subject, seems to indicate that it shouldn't be done or is bad practice.

I asked [yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32756143/rails-associations-has-many-through-ban-archive-solution) about a has_many relationship, but thought because I couldn't find information on this, I would generate a question so it is easier for people to search for this in the future.  I'm paraphrasing another users answer (I hope this is ok).

A Shoe can have many Socks, but only one active Sock. Other Socks are inactive. All Socks are also unique with unique patterns. I want to make sure I don't have socks with the same pattern. I think I can do this three ways

```
class Sock < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :shoe
end
```

To find out if a Sock is active or inactive, give its' owner shoe a reference to its active sock like so:

```
class Shoe < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sock
end
```

Go to its owner Shoe and check if the Shoe's active sock is the current Sock or not. E.g.

```
def is_active
  owner_shoe.active_sock == self
```

Associate them with foreign keys

```
class CreateGettingDressed < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :shoes do |t|
      t.belongs_to :active_sock, foreign_key: "sock_id"
      t.string :size
      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    create_table :socks do |t|
      t.belongs :owner_shoe, foreign_key: "shoe_id"
      t.string :pattern
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is your two pieces of functionality are conflicting:

> A `Shoe` can have many `Socks`, but only one active `Sock`

You're looking to associate the two models on two different associations. Although this is simply done, I feel the way you're trying to do is is a little restricted.

Here's how I'd set up the base association:

```
#app/models/sock.rb
class Sock < ActiveRecord::Base
   #columns id | shoe_id | name | active (boolean) | created_at | updated_at
   belongs_to :shoe
end

#app/models/shoe.rb
class Shoe < ActiveRecord::Base
   #columns id | name | etc | created_at | updated_at
   has_many :socks
   scope :active, -> { where(active: true).first }
end
```

This will give you the ability to call:

```
@shoe = Shoe.find 1
@shoe.socks.active #-> first sock with "active" boolean as true
```

It will also negate the need to include an `active?` method in your `sock` model. You can call `@shoe.socks.find(2).active?` to get a response as to whether it's active or not.

---

Now, this *should* work pretty well for basic functionality.

However, you mention several extensions:

> if a Sock is `active` or `inactive`
>
> I want to make sure I don't have socks with the same pattern

This adds extra specifications which I'd tackle with a `join` model ([`has_many :through`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)):

```
#app/models/sock.rb
class Sock < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :shoe_socks
   has_many :shoes, through: :shoe_socks
end

#app/models/shoe_sock.rb
class ShoeSock < ActiveRecord::Base
   # columns id | shoe_id | sock_id | pattern_id | active | created_at | updated_at
   belongs_to :shoe
   belongs_to :sock
   belongs_to :pattern
end

#app/models/shoe.rb
class Shoe < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :shoe_socks
   has_many :socks, through: :shoe_socks, extend: ActiveSock
   scope :active, -> { where(active: true).first }
end
```

You can read more about the below code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21401629/accessing-parent-through-unsaved-child-association-has-many-through):

```
#app/models/concerns/active_sock.rb
module ActiveSock

    #Load
    def load
      captions.each do |caption|
          proxy_association.target << active
      end
    end

    #Private
    private

    #Captions
    def captions
            return_array = []
            through_collection.each_with_index do |through,i|
                    associate = through.send(reflection_name)
                    associate.assign_attributes({active: items[i]})
                    return_array.concat Array.new(1).fill( associate )
            end
            return_array
    end

    #######################
    #      Variables      #
    #######################

    #Association
    def reflection_name
            proxy_association.source_reflection.name
    end

    #Foreign Key
    def through_source_key
            proxy_association.reflection.source_reflection.foreign_key
    end

    #Primary Key
    def through_primary_key
              proxy_association.reflection.through_reflection.active_record_primary_key
    end

    #Through Name
    def through_name
            proxy_association.reflection.through_reflection.name
    end

    #Through
    def through_collection
            proxy_association.owner.send through_name
    end

    #Captions
    def items
            through_collection.map(&:active)
    end

    #Target
    def target_collection
            #load_target
            proxy_association.target
    end
```

This setup will basically put all the "logic" into the join model. IE you'll have a database of *socks*, one of *shoes* and a connecting DB with parings of both.

This will still permit you to call `@shoe.socks.active` but without having to degrade the data integrity in your data models.

I have also added some code I wrote a while back - which gives you the ability to access attributes from the join model. It uses the `proxy_association` object in ActiveRecord, so it doesn't invoke any more SQL.

This added code will append the `active?` attribute to any associative `Sock` objects.

Answer (score 4):

In Rails, `belongs_to` is an indicator that the model has a *foreign key*. For instance, if a sock `belongs_to` a shoe, then your sock table will have a `shoe_id` field. There's [a number of associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) available to you, but having both shoes and socks use `belongs_to` sounds needlessly complex.

The most straightforward solution is to change the language a little bit, and think of each sock as having one active shoe. That way if you switch a sock to another shoe, then you don't have anything to tidy up on the shoe. Your data's more likely to remain consistent that way.

```
class Shoe < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :sock
end

class Sock < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :shoe
end
```

You can now call `shoe.sock` to get a shoe's active sock, or `sock.shoe` to get a sock's shoe.

---

Alternatively, maybe you'd like each shoe to have a dedicated pool of socks. We can extend our previous solution to support that, name our relationship `active_sock` to make things clearer, and use a validator to make sure that our sock is from the pool:

```
class Shoe < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :socks
  has_one :active_sock, class_name: "Sock", foreign_key: "active_shoe_id"

  validates :active_sock_id, inclusion: { in: sock_ids }
end

class Sock < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :shoe

  def active?
    shoe.active_sock == self
  end
end
```

Now you can call `shoe.socks` to get all the available socks for a shoe, and `shoe.active_sock` to get the active sock. From the sock side, then `sock.shoe` returns which shoe "owns" this sock, and `sock.active?` returns whether this sock is currently active.